# How can I get a value from the ecommerce array as a custom variable in Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a site that has Tag Manager installed and I have the following in the data layer:

```js
window.dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'currencyCode': 'USD',
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '2851743',
        'affiliation': 'MOS: 8',
        'revenue': 75.00,
        'tax': .00,
        'shipping': 12.00,
        'coupon': ''
      },
      'products': [

        {
          'brand': 'Existing Customer',

          'name': 'Product Name',
          'id': '1216M18',
          'price': '63',
          'category': 'Tickets',
          'variant': '12/16/17 2pm',
          'quantity': '1',
          'dimension2': 'Saturday'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

I have a tag in tag manager that is a non-analytics tag and I need to pull values from the data layer, such as ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue or ecommerce.purchase.products.id and use them as a custom variable in Tag Manager so they can be added to my tag.

However I can't seem to get the values using the format: ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue

I am putting this inside of the "Data Layer Variable Name" field on the variable configuration window in the variables section of Tag Manager.

Is there another way I can get these items?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that when you push data to the datalayer you need to send an event with it, else the variables are not updates within GTM, which is potentially a reason why you cannot get at the values.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, referring to those values in the enhanced ecomm spec will be highly flawed. I would strongly suggest you do the following:

1. In a second dataLayer push, send the appropriate revenue, product IDs, etc that are relevant for this second tag

`dataLayer.push({event:"secondRevenue", revenue: "XXX", products: [XXX]})`

2. Set a trigger to fire your alternative tag on `event = "secondRevenue"`
3. Create variables that are equal to `dataLayer.revenue` and `dataLayer.products` and associate/consume them in your second tag

Comment: In what way will be referring to the EEC object be flawed ?

Answer (score 0):

ecommerce.purchase.products.id won't work, try ecommerce.purchase.products.**i**.id where **i** is the index of the object in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable you're trying to access is inside an object (like "revenue" in your example), then you can access it like this:

`ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue`

If the variable you're trying to access is inside an array and your array only contains a single element (like "price" in your example), then you can access it like this:

`ecommerce.purchase.products.0.price`